# Getting the response time data from Jmeter to csv

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to save the response time for the load test to a csv File. I am getting the following graph. But is there a way I can store the data points of these to a separate file so, I can work on them manually.
[image]

Even the configuration doesn't have an option to save the response time
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

[image]

Check out [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) to learn what do these metrics mean

> **Elapsed time**. JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received. JMeter does not include the time needed to render the response, nor does JMeter process any client code, for example Javascript.

In general using Listeners is not very recommended because [Listeners don't add any value, they just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/). Neither it's recommended to use JMeter GUI for load tests execution, you should be using GUI mode only for tests development and debugging.

So:

1. Disable all the listeners
2. Run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t /path/to/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/test/result.jtl
   ```

Once the test finishes you will have all the "datapoints" in the `result.jtl` file, if you need to visualize it you can open it with the Listener of your choice (using "Browse" button) or generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) from it